# dataweave filter and maxBy on nested array list

Tags: mulesoft

I have a list of students and their marks for respective subjects. I want to filter all students of a specific grades and then find the student who got maximum marks in a specific object.

```
[
  {
    "name": "User 01",
    "grade": 1,
    "schoolName": "school01",
    "marks": {
      "english": 10,
      "math": 30,
      "social": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "User 02",
    "grade": 1,
    "schoolName": "school02",
    "marks": {
      "english": 10,
      "math": 20,
      "social": 30
    }
  }
]
```

I am able to perform both the operations independently. can someone help me find the student object who got max marks in math in a specific grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I used it below to achieve it.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var grade = 1
var topic = "math"
---
payload filter (
    ((item, index) ->  item.grade == grade) 
) maxBy ($.marks.math as String {format: "000000"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly this script does it. Just change the variables grade and topic to the specific values you are interested in.

Generally speaking it is always better to provide example outputs and whatever you got as script to understand better the context, in addition to the input samples.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var grade = 1
var topic = "math"
---
flatten( 
    payload map (alumn, order) -> 
        (alumn.marks pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
            {
                name: alumn.name, 
                grade: alumn.grade, 
                result:value, 
                topic: key
            })
        )
) // restructure the list to one result per element
filter ((item, index) -> (item.grade == grade)) // filter by grade
maxBy ((item) -> item.result) // get the maximum result
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. For frist grade students, who received maximum marks in math...result should be {
    "name": "User 01",
    "grade": 1,
    "schoolName": "school01",
    "marks": {
      "english": 10,
      "math": 30,
      "social": 30
    }
  }

Comment: Please edit the question to include the expected output.